# Performance of Computed Observable With Dropdownlist

Tags: knockout.js

I am having an issue with my template being re-rendered on each item pushed into my observable array called "games".  It is being caused by a computed observable called "gamesCount" that needs to send a subscription to everyone to update their arrays with the new count.  If I remove "gamesCount" from the code altogether runs fast.  I have 128 dropdowns sharing this array with "gamesCount", and need them to update on how many "games" there are.  How can I improve the performance on this?

```
app.viewModel.members.bracket = {
        games: ko.observableArray([
            { left: ko.observable(50), top: ko.observable(50), height: ko.observable(96), width: ko.observable(150), reverse: false, type: 1, awayTeam: { display: ko.observable('') }, homeTeam: { display: ko.observable('')} },
            { left: ko.observable(50), top: ko.observable(150), height: ko.observable(96), width: ko.observable(150), reverse: false, type: 1, awayTeam: { display: ko.observable('') }, homeTeam: { display: ko.observable('')} },
            { left: ko.observable(50), top: ko.observable(250), height: ko.observable(96), width: ko.observable(150), reverse: false, type: 1, awayTeam: { display: ko.observable('') }, homeTeam: { display: ko.observable('')} },
            { left: ko.observable(800), top: ko.observable(232), height: ko.observable(426), width: ko.observable(150), reverse: true, type: 1, awayTeam: { display: ko.observable('') }, homeTeam: { display: ko.observable('')} }
        ]),
    };

app.viewModel.members.bracket.gameCount = ko.computed(function () {
        var games = this.games().length;

        var numbers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < games; i++) {
            numbers.push(i + 1);
        }
            return numbers;

}, app.viewModel.members.bracket);

        <div data-bind="foreach: members.bracket.games">
              @Html.DropDownList("GameNumber", new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<string>()), new { @class = "select-bracket", data_bind = "options: $root.members.bracket.gameCount, dropdownlist: {}, optionsCaption:' - Game - '" })                      
        </div>
```

Comment: Not quite related, but why use razor to create an empty select, without any reference to a razor model? Wouldn't it be simpler and easier to just write the select out?

Comment: I will eventually turn the view into a strongly typed modal, which will use the DropdownListFor.  I like to get my names strongly typed.

Comment: This article might help: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Comment: This may be negligible, but do you know an approximate maximum number of games? If so maybe you could build that array of numbers once and then use something like Array.splice to return the set you need within the computed function rather than building a new array each time?

Comment: The trouble is, even if the gameCount function itself is super fast and even if you use valueHasMutated to limit the number of recalculations, Knockout still has to build 128 sets of new select options at least once - and I guess that's a lot of DOM. Roughly how many games are there at any time, i.e. how many options per select? Do you find that the performance is basically proportional to the number of selects?

Answer (score 0):

Tom may be right about DOM manipulation and the N<sup>2</sup> number of list items that need to get created for each update of the `games` array. The least you can do is optimize the `games` array creation with something like this:

```
vm.gameCount = ko.computed(function () {
  var games = this.games().length,
    numbers = new Array(games);

  for (var i = 0; i < games; i++) {
    numbers[i] = i + 1;
  }

  return numbers;
}, vm);
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevingorski/BGEyx/3/)

This probably isn't as efficient as keeping the game # array around and making only the necessary changes to it on computation, but it's readable.